# How can I generate email alerts using java whenever my code fails

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, dao

So,I've this new requirement of generating email alerts to myself to get to know if my code is failing. The message body should be StackTrace of code failure.I've a DAO Class written in java with CRUD DB operation implementations.If my code fails at a particular operation i've to generate an email alert. How can i do it in Java ?

Comment: Start reading at the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ).

Answer (score 1):

Hi I am a very simple flow, 
Write a Simple mail class,access and use in in your Program Class in Exceptions
[image]